# Get information about Contacts with Accouts - SugarCRM

Tags: php, api, rest, sugarcrm

I have problem with get contacts with accounts related. I try to find contact using office phone as search filter, joined with account (with customer fields). How can I make it?

I was try do this with relation:

```
$search = array(
            'session' => $this->connect(),
            'module_name' => 'Accounts',
            'module_id' => '1155847e-49a8-c077-4c6a-53e8b0ac91ca',
            'link_field_name' => 'contacts',
            'related_module_query' => "contacts.phone_office = '{$phoneNumber}'",
            'related_fields' => array('custom_field_c'),
            'related_module_link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'contacts',
                    'value' => array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name'),
                ),
            ),
            'deleted' => 0,
            'offset' => 0,
            'limit' => 10
        );
```

but this way is incorrect because I don't know anything about `module_id` property.

Previously version was:

```
$search = array(
            'session' => $this->connect(),
            'module_name' => "Contacts",
            'query' => "contacts.phone_office = '{$phoneNumber}'",
            'offset' => 0,
            'select_fields' => $this->fields,
            'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(),
            'max_results' => 0,
            'deleted' => 0,
            'Favorites' => false,
        );
```

this was working but I didn't have any infos about account and account custom fields related with contact.

Is any outer way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be pedantic about it, you should specify the version of Sugar and the version of the API you're using. I'll assume it's 4_1.

I notice in your first request you don't have a 'query' or 'order_by' parameter. I understand the API requires parameters to be in a specific order. I'd try adding these back in. You also lack the 'select_fields' param.

I have an example of this in a document I've written here: [SugarCRM REST API (v4_1) : List Accounts with Related Contacts](https://gist.github.com/matthewpoer/b9366ca4197a521a600f#list-accounts-with-related-contacts).